# example of a physical phenomenon

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, markov-chains, markov-process

can anyone give an example of a physical system(phenomena) that often arises in the field of engineering research whose states-space has to be taken as a complete separable metric space(I precisely do not want compact metric space), and that system can be modeled as a discrete-time Markov chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Queues in queueing theory:** the system is modeled using a discrete-time Markov chain, where the state of the queue is the number of elements in the system

Harchol-Balter, M. (2013). Performance modeling and design of computer systems: queueing theory in action. Cambridge University Press.

**Ising model,** in Physics: it is used in Engineering research and machine learning to remove noise from images

Bishop, C. M. (2006). Pattern recognition and machine learning. Springer.

section 8.3.3

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model#Viewing_the_Ising_model_as_a_Markov_chain

https://github.com/AmazaspShumik/BayesianML-MCMC/blob/master/Gibbs%20Ising%20Model/imageDenoisingExample.m

Comment: Thank you!!! but I don't think states-space has taken as a complete separable metric space in your first reference, they also deal with finite state-space Markov chain, not discrete-time Markov chain in general metric space.

Comment: Also for the second reference, could you highlight the chapter name in which it is described?

Comment: The first book will be in any way helpful for me Thanks!

Comment: section 8.3.3 -- added there